# How to have the polarity of a circuit bypass a pulse width modulator?

Tags: circuit-design, diodes, switches, dc, pwm

Power supply: 12 V DC

Load: modified micro servo, now just a geared-down DC motor

A pulse width modulator (PWM) is used to drive the motor at a lower speed. I initially intended to control the direction of rotation of the motor by changing the polarity of the supplied 12 V DC, but the PWM only functions correctly when powered one way.

To solve this, I need two circuits that I do not know how to build:

1. One that will ensure the correct polarity of the PWM input
2. Another that will take the output of the PWM, which will be < 5 V DC, and change its polarity depending on the polarity of the 12 V provided.

I'm pretty sure #1 can be done with just 4 diodes, but #2 may drive me down a rabbit hole that the noob that I am does not want to go down.

Comment: This sounds like it can be handled by a standard off-the-shelf H-bridge microcontroller capable of PWM - it can both reverse the direction of applied voltage to the motor, and pulse it, as two core functionalities of the same one device. If this doesn't work for you, can you elaborate on why not?

Comment: Do you mean logically invert when you say change the polarity? If not, what do you mean?

Comment: Tell us the name or part-number of the microservo what you want to use. Normally you have 3 pins on a servo cable, GND, V+ and signal. The signal is a PWM-signal and the duration of the on-time describes the position of the servo. 0.5 milliseconds = left. 1 ms = center, 1.5 ms = right. So you do not have to change the polarity, the internal electronic of the servo is doing this for you.

Comment: @Andyaka I don't know what “logically invert” means exactly, but I can say “swap the positive and the negative”, like one would do using a DPDT switch.

Comment: @MikroPower The servo motor is no longer a /servo/ motor, as I gutted it so it would just be a geared down motor, which is what I meant by “dumbed micro servo”

Comment: There are little chips available, they have a H-bridge inside. https://www.st.com/en/automotive-analog-and-power/l9960.html or Possibly: L293D